# How to add zeros in front of a text field in an access table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an access table with a text field. It has alpha numeric values. But i want all values to be minimum 3 digit. so i want to add zeroes in front of all single or two digit values

.

```
5  must become 005
89 must become 089
```

how do i write a query to update all values in the table.

thanks
tksy

Comment: What do you mean by "digit value"? What happens when the alphanumeric value has one or two characters but is not considered to be a "digit value"? What happens when the value is the empty string? What happens when the value is NULL?

Comment: Why do you want to store data in the wrong format? This seems to me like something that should be done in the presentation layer and not stored formatted in the database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key is to add as many zeros as needed to take the length up to 3.

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET YourField = LEFT("00", 3-LEN(YourField)) + YourField
WHERE LEN(YourField)<3 AND Len(YourField)>0
```

Comment: Of the answers, your included the most information.  Mine assumes too much prior knowledge of the user.

Comment: Note the question states "in front of all single or two digit values".

Comment: @onedaywhen - thanks for the pointer, what you say is correct. I've updated the query accordingly. On my initial reading I assumed that either there were no NULL values/empty strings, or that they should be changed to 000. An explicit mention of these cases in the question would have been clearer to close any room for misinterpretation.

Answer (score 2):

```
update tbl
set Col1 = RIGHT("000" + Col1,3)
where len(Col1) < 3
```

Comment: Note the question states "in front of all single or two digit values".

Answer (score 1):

While its usually important to try to do as much as possible in one SQL statement (to help the optimizer for OLTP applications etc), this appears to be a data corruption scenario so I assume a one-off data scrubbing exercise is all that's required. And when you consider there's only two cases ("single or two digit values") there's no real harm in using two `UPDATE` statements e.g.

```
UPDATE Test1
   SET text_col = '0' + text_col
 WHERE text_col ALIKE '[0-9][0-9]';

UPDATE Test1
   SET text_col = '00' + text_col
 WHERE text_col ALIKE '[0-9]';
```

HOWEVER, the most important part of the exercise is to apply data constraints to ensure the data corruption doesn't reoccur e.g. (ANSI-92 SQL Mode syntax):

```
ALTER TABLE Test1 ADD
   CONSTRAINT text_col__numeric__at_least_three_digits
   CHECK (
          text_col NOT ALIKE '[0-9]'
          AND text_col NOT ALIKE '[0-9][0-9]'
         );
```

Answer (score 1):

Create --> Query Design --> Update Query

Select the variable you want to update, then in the update to field, type:

Format([variable name],"0000000")

I used 7 zeros above because I wanted the to fill in zeros in the beginning of a number string up to 7 places total.

Note that this can be used only for a text field.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can prefix 3 zeros to the front and then substring out the last 3 digits from the right.  Something like `right("000" + val, 3)` if those were real function.

I think in Access it is `MID("000" & val, 3, 3)`

Comment: I think Access has a `Right` function http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/right-function-HA001228900.aspx

Comment: Here are the other string functions, including LEFT. http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/using-string-manipulation-functions-HA001054727.aspx

Comment: Note the question states "in front of all single or two digit values".

Answer (score 0):

**ACCESS**

```
SELECT FORMAT(startTable.numField,"00#") AS txtField
FROM startTable
WHERE startTable.numField IS NOT NULL;
```

...

```
UPDATE destinationTable
SET destinationTable.txtField = FORMAT(startTable.numField,"00#")
WHERE startTable.numField IS NOT NULL;
```

...

```
INSERT INTO destinationTable ( txtField )
SELECT FORMAT(startTable.numField,"00#") AS txtField
FROM startTable
WHERE startTable.numField IS NOT NULL;
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT RIGHT('000' + CAST(numField AS VARCHAR(3)), 3) AS txtField
FROM startTable
WHERE startTable.numField IS NOT NULL
```

...

```
UPDATE destinationTable
SET destinationTable.txtField = RIGHT('000' + CAST(startTable.numField AS VARCHAR(3)), 3)
WHERE startTable.numField IS NOT NULL
```

...

```
INSERT INTO destinationTable ( txtField )
SELECT RIGHT('000' + CAST(numField AS VARCHAR(3)), 3) AS txtField
FROM startTable
WHERE startTable.numField IS NOT NULL
```